# Error con Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Tags: visual-studio, vb.net, excel

Apenas estoy aprendiendo y precisamente en el primer videotutorial me encuentro con este problema que cuando doy clic en el botón me aparece el siguiente error:

> System.MissingMemberException: 'Public member 'cells' on type 'Worksheet' not found.'

Mi código es:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Conectar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Conectar.Click
        Dim excelapp = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
        Dim libro = excelapp.Workbooks.Add

        libro.Sheets(1).cells(1, 1) = "hola mundo"
        libro.SaveAs(Filename:="C:\Users\HP\Desktop\test1.xlsx")

        Label1.Text = "El registro fue enviado con éxito"
        excelapp.Quit()

        libro = Nothing
        excelapp = Nothing
    End Sub
End Class
```

Agradecería mucho su ayuda y también consejos para poder solucionar estas cosas por mi cuenta, soy nuevo en *Visual Basic*.

Comment: Debes revisar esta linea, `libro.Sheets(1).cells(1, 1) = "hola mundo"`, la propiedad `cells` devuelve un objeto `Range` y en tu código, le estas asignando un valor de tipo `string`; prueba usar `libro.Sheets(1).cells(1, 1).Text = "hola mundo"` o  `libro.Sheets(1).cells(1, 1).Formula = "hola mundo"`

Comment: Prueba con `libro.Sheets(1).Cells[1, 1].Value = "hola mundo"`

Comment: He copiado y pegado los códigos y me sigue apareciendo el mismo error :(, pienso que puede ser error del Visual Studio, de igual manera muchas gracias